# Django-social-auth extended facebook permissions like spotify

Tags: python, django, facebook

I was able to get the publish_actions permission for my facebook app by using this setting

```
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['publish_actions']
```

The problem is that when authorizing my facebook app is that a second window is used to prompt the user to allow my app to publish actions after the initial prompt for the basic info.

How can I use only one window to get users to authorize my app? I'm trying to get my authorization window to look similar spotify's authorization

[image: spotify facebook request]

Answer (score 0):

Django-social-auth has been superseded by python-social-auth. In python-social-auth, you define extended permission by using `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE` inside settings.py. For example:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'user_photos']
```

It will only show a single authorization dialog.